# Do i need to create a account for nagios user in linux

Tags: linux, centos

I have installed `NAGIOS` on `centos` and its working fine.

I want to try commands from nagios user but when i do

`su nagios` from user then get this

`This account is currently not available.`

But web interface is working fine . so i want to know whats the problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I use:

```
  su - nagios -s /bin/bash
```

Which changes to the nagios user with the nagios user's environment using the shell "/bin/bash"

Answer (score 2):

This message indicates that the account has been disabled by setting its shell (probably to `/sbin/nologon`).  You can still run commands with that user's privileges if you want to; there are many ways to do this.  For example, you can use su:

```
su nagios -s /bin/bash
```

Or you can use sudo:

```
sudo -u nagios <command>
```

The trick is just to get around running the user's default shell.  Other things like cron jobs or suid programs which use this account, and certainly nagios, will work fine; the message only means that the user can't log in and get a shell.